# Change Text Dynamically of Table Data

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to change the the text of a table element based on the the choice of an input of a select tag.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kdt0jn1/23/) of it.

```
<html>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">People - 2
                <div id="people" class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="POST" id="update">
                            <b>Person - 1</b>
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <b>First Name:</b> <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="Jonny Boy"> <br>
                                            <b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="Smith"> <br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $<input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" size="3" maxlength="3" value="25">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Wristband(s):</b>
                                            <select name="wristSelection" class="wristbands">
                                    <option value="No Wrist Bands">No Wrist Bands</option>
                                    <option value="1 X $50">1 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="2 X $50">2 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="3 X $50">3 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="4 X $50" selected="">4 X $50</option>
                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$200.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Friday Event:</b>
                                            <select id="friday" name="friday">
                                    <option value="Yes" selected="">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="No">No</option>
                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn">Update Person 1</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <form method="POST" id="golferUpdate">
                            <b>Person - 2</b>
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <b>First Name:</b> <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="William"> <br>
                                            <b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="Jefferson"> <br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $<input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" size="3" maxlength="3" value="150">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Wristband(s):</b>
                                            <select name="wristSelection" class="wristbands">
                                    <option value="No Wrist Bands">No Wrist Bands</option>
                                    <option value="1 X $50">1 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="2 X $50" selected="">2 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="3 X $50">3 X $50</option>
                                    <option value="4 X $50">4 X $50</option>
                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$100.00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Friday Event:</b>
                                            <select id="friday" name="friday">
                                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="No" selected="">No</option>
                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><button class="btn">Update Person 2</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>$475.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wrist = document.getElementsByClassName("wristbands");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < wrist.length; i++) {
            wrist[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (wrist[i].value == "No Wrist Bands") {
                    content.innerHTML = "$0.00";
                } else {
                    var wristbands = wrist[i].value.split(" ");
                    var amount = wristbands[2].replace("$", "");
                    var qty = wristbands[0];
                    content.innerHTML = "$" + amount * qty + ".00";
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

So as seen above I have a select tag to choose the number of wristbands you want to purchase. I want it to up the following td to update the total cost. I have the javascript function below it. I am trying to add a event listener on change that it will grab the value of the one selected, splits it, then mutliplies them together to get the total. I have another similar js function that does the same thing but it is on click and it works.

I'm fairly new to JS and am kinda stuck. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do it this way. You were pretty close.

```
        var wrist =  document.querySelectorAll(".wristbands");

        wrist.forEach(function(elem) {
          elem.addEventListener("change", function(element) {
            var content = element.currentTarget.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
            if (element.currentTarget.value === "No Wrist Bands") {
                content.innerHTML = "$0.00";
            } else {
                var wristbands = element.currentTarget.value.split(" ");
                var amount = wristbands[2].replace("$", "");
                var qty = wristbands[0];
                content.innerHTML = "$" + amount * qty + ".00";
            }
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues with the code.

1. When the 'change' callback is called, `this` is the `<select>` tag, which doesn't have any sibling. I think you want the `<td>` with the price. So, I would change it to `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling`, that way it grabs the parent `<td>` of `<select>` first.
2. By the time `wrist[i]` is referenced inside of the callback, the for loop has already been completed with the value of `i` being 2, so when `wrist[i]` is used inside of the callback, it's really grabbing `wrist[2]`, which of course is undefined. I would use event.currentTarget which is where the change event triggered.

   `for (i = 0; i < wrist.length; i++) {
       wrist[i].addEventListener("change", function(_event) {
           var content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
           var selectTag = _event.currentTarget;
           if (selectTag.value == "No Wrist Bands") {
               content.innerHTML = "$0.00";
           } else {
               var wristbands = selectTag.value.split(" ");
               var amount = wristbands[2].replace("$", "");
               var qty = wristbands[0];
               content.innerHTML = "$" + amount * qty + ".00";
           }
       });
   }`

Answer (score 0):

To get current element where you changed you can add parameter to function

```
var wrist = document.getElementsByClassName("wristbands");

for (var i = 0; i < wrist.length; i++) {
    wrist[i].addEventListener("change", function(element) {
        var content = element.currentTarget.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        if (element.currentTarget.value === "No Wrist Bands") {
            content.innerHTML = "$0.00";
        } else {
            var wristbands = element.currentTarget.value.split(" ");
            var amount = wristbands[2].replace("$", "");
            var qty = wristbands[0];
            content.innerHTML = "$" + amount * qty + ".00";
        }
    });
}
```